# View of taxonomy with node count grouped by another taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy *foo* with a fixed number of values (6).
E.g. [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6]

I have nodes related to this taxonomy (from 0 to n).
This nodes are classified with another taxonomy *bar*, with 3 values possible (X, Y, Z).

I have a view, based on the *foo* taxonomy, with this results

```
**A1**
34 nodes

**A2**
29 nodes

**A3**
40 nodes
```

etc.

I would like to have a view with this results:

```
**A1**
20 X
11 Y
3 Z

**A2**
9 X
10 Y
10 Z

**A2**
12 X
20 Y
8 Z
```

etc.

What can be the best approach?